# Algorithm to Create Unique User Id with Objective C

Tags: java, c#, ios, objective-c

I am creating an online social app.
I need a way to create a lot of random unique ID like userId, chatRoom Id things like that.
Not only that, I want to make sure that this algorithm can be created with Java or C#.
Should I use NSUUID? everytime you create a new NSUUID it will create a new unique string right?
Or is there any easy way I can create one using timeStamp?

Comment: Normally having disparate language tags is a bad thing, but this use is actually reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for that. Java and C# have implementations to generate them. In Java use  `java.util.UUID.randomUUID();`  in C# you can use `Guid.NewGuid();`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Hashids](http://hashids.org/).

I believe it has versions for multiple languages and would suit your needs.